# Adding text to a 3d model using sceneform arcore android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, texture-mapping, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to build a app using arcore and sceneform. For that I want to add text to a 3d model. The text should appear in a particular position in the model.Is that possible using sceneform?

Can anyone give suggestion as to how to proceed?

Comment: Yeah, Its possible and its very easy to do it. go through this link - https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/177

Answer (score 2):

Text can be added using [ViewRenderable](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ViewRenderable), worked with filament version 1.7.0, crashes in some lower versions

[Reference](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/1548ff3c6ebd4750bf97250e1fea5f61ff6a1c4c/samples/gltf/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/gltf/GltfActivity.java)

```
Node tigerTitleNode = new Node();
      tigerTitleNode.setParent(model);
      tigerTitleNode.setEnabled(false);
      tigerTitleNode.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
      ViewRenderable.builder()
              .setView(this, R.layout.tiger_card_view)
              .build()
              .thenAccept(
                      (renderable) -> {
                          tigerTitleNode.setRenderable(renderable);
                          tigerTitleNode.setEnabled(true);
                      })
              .exceptionally(
                      (throwable) -> {
                          throw new AssertionError("Could not load card view.", throwable);
                      }
              );
    });
```

tiger_card_view.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:text="Tiger"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Comment: not working for me in 1.6 can't really find any resources online.. Are there any walk arounds?? Can it be implemented directly in Filament? sceneform 1.6 uses Filament 1.4.5.. Cant rally upgrade it to use a higher version without breaking everything else

Comment: Here is a commit that uses filament 1.7 https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/1548ff3c6ebd4750bf97250e1fea5f61ff6a1c4c

Comment: OMG Atul yes! Its working! I literally  love you! Wasted so much time on this one.. Was about to give up and downgrade `sceneform` to 1.15 and go back to `sfb/sfa` system - Thank you!! Wish you a life of joy and happiness!